# NiceMatrix how to split first column into three/four part

Tags: nicematrix

I would like to divide the first column of my matrix into four subsections. The issue is that it works when I split it into three subsections. Please take a look at the image.

[image: a matrix with three part first column]

However, when I add another section, I receive an error message `Missing = inserted for \ifnum`. Additionally, the matrix becomes distorted. Please refer to the picture for visual context.

[image: look at the fourth part]

Please note that if you, for example, remove the first section (the section related to `\gamma_{rd}`), it functions correctly without any errors. I suspect there might be an issue with adding a(any) fourth section. Could you provide guidance on resolving this?

Lastly, I have included my code below for reference.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

% set font encoding for PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaTeX
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\if\ifxetex T\else\ifluatex T\else F\fi\fi T%
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Name of Author}

% Enable SageTeX to run SageMath code right inside this LaTeX file.
% http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html
% \usepackage{sagetex}

% Enable PythonTeX to run Python – https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex
% \usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\maketitle



$A_{B_0} = B_0 = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,nullify-dots]
& \Ldots[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]^{Base\ columns\ (index\ \lambda)} \\
\Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{3}_{\gamma_{rd}} \hspace*{10pt}& \gamma_{11,1} & \cdots & \gamma_{11,\lambda} & \cdots  \\
  & \vdots &   & \vdots&  &  \\
  & \gamma_{|R||D|, 1} & \cdots & \gamma_{|R||D|,\lambda} & \cdots  \\ \hline
\Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{3}_{x_{p}} & x_{1,1} & \cdots & x_{1,\lambda} & \cdots \\
  & \vdots &   & \vdots&  &  \\
 & x_{|P|, 1}  & \cdots & x_{|P|,\lambda} & \cdots\\\hline
\Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{3}_{y_{p}} & y_{1,1} & \cdots & y_{1,\lambda} & \cdots\\
  & \vdots &   & \vdots&  &  \\
 &y_{|S|, 1} &  \cdots & y_{|S|,\lambda} & \cdots & 
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\hspace{20pt}

$A_{B_1} = B_1 = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,nullify-dots]
& \Ldots[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]^{Base\ columns\ (index\ \lambda)} \\
\Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{3}_{\gamma_{rd}} \hspace*{10pt}& \gamma_{11,1} & \cdots & \gamma_{11,\lambda} & \cdots  \\
  & \vdots &   & \vdots&  &  \\
  & \gamma_{|R||D|, 1} & \cdots & \gamma_{|R||D|,\lambda} & \cdots  \\ \hline
\Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{3}_{x_{p}} & x_{1,1} & \cdots & x_{1,\lambda} & \cdots \\
  & \vdots &   & \vdots&  &  \\
 & x_{|P|, 1}  & \cdots & x_{|P|,\lambda} & \cdots\\ \hline
\Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{3}_{y_{p}} & y_{1,1} & \cdots & y_{1,\lambda} & \cdots\\
  & \vdots &   & \vdots&  &  \\
 &y_{|S|, 1} &  \cdots & y_{|S|,\lambda} & \cdots & \\ \hline
  \Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{1}_{gCut_{g}} & \digamma (\xi_{\beta, 1})  & \cdots & \digamma (\xi_{\beta, \lambda})  & \cdots 
\end{pNiceMatrix}$



\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide a full compilable MWE  (with the documentclass, etc.)

Comment: I did not fully understand what you need, but I changed the code section to add a complete ready-to-run document, if it is not what you meant, give me some more explanation.

Comment: Yes. Now, it's a MWE (minimal working example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

That bug has been corrected in version 6.21a 2023-07-17 of `nicematrix`.

---

That's a bug of `nicematrix`. Somewhere in the code, I have written `\int_compare:nNnTF #1 = 1` instead of `\int_compare:nNnTF { #1 } = 1`.

It will be corrected soon on CTAN.

If you want right now a corrected version of `nicematrix.sty`, send me an email (you will find my address on the documentation of `nicematrix`: `nicematrix.pdf`).

Comment: I also suspected that, thank you for your effort. Look forward to using the new version.

Comment: Hello, I've come to the realization that having four sections isn't an issue. However, encountering an error when initiating a new section after row 9 (for instance, row 10, ...) is problematic. The provided code contains four sections, and because the fourth section is located at row 9, the program currently executes without any issues.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\begin{document}
$ B^1 = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,nullify-dots]
& \Ldots[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]^{Base} \\
  \Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{3}_{gg} \hspace*{10pt}&  & & &  \\
  & &  & & & \\
  & &  & & &\\ 
\Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{3}_{x} &  & & & \\
  &  & & & \\
 &  & & &\\ 
\Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{3}_{y} &  & & &\\
 &  & & & \\
   \Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=blue]{2}_{g} &  & & &\\
   &  & & &\\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}`

Comment: I think that your last `\Vdotsfor[...]{3}_{y}` should be `\Vdotsfor[...]{2}_{Y}` (or you should add one row more).

Comment: You are correct. I removed some information to stay within the character limit for the comment. However, the original code in the original post is not functioning as intended. The issue lies in the fact that the fourth section begins after the 9th row. To resolve this, if you adjust the 3rd section to span two rows, you can define the fourth section without encountering any issues. I hope I've explained this adequately. That is why I thought if you know this, it would be helpful in the new version.

Comment: You should present your problem in another question on this site. It's not easy to solve a problem in the comments.